# App Service Access restriction on VNet using automation

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I want to add restriction to my webApp on VNet and not ip address. 
I can do that on the UI going to Networking -> Access Restriction.

Can anyone port how do this with PowerShell, CLI or ARM please

Answer (score 0):

There **currently is no CLI or PowerShell for the new Access Restrictions capability** but the values can be **set manually with an Azure REST API PUT operation** on the app configuration in Resource Manager.

As an example, you can use `resources.azure.com` and edit the `ipSecurityRestrictions` block to add the required JSON.

The location for this information in Resource Manager is:

```
management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription ID/resourceGroups/resource groups/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/web app name/config/web?api-version=2018-02-01
```

The JSON syntax for the earlier example is:

```
{
  "properties": {
      "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
      {
        "vnetSubnetResourceId": "/subscriptions/your Subscription ID/resourceGroups/yourVnetResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/yourvnetName/subnets/default",
        "action": "Allow",
        "tag": "Default",
        "priority": 300,
        "name": "vnetrule1",
        "description": "vnet"
      }
      ]
   }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#programmatic-manipulation-of-access-restriction-rules).